Angular ActivatedRoute by ID return null or Undefined
I want to pull data from the API to the dialog form by id for editing using activatedroute. When I define the ID section in URL, it returns as undefined or null. However, when I enter ID section in URL manually, I can pull data into the form. I think there is a problem with activatedroute. I would like to ask for help from those who have knowledge of this subject.
ngOnInit(): void {

    this.loadWaters();
    // this.id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get['id'];
    // this.id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    // this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
    //   console.log(params.get('id'));
    // });

    this.loadProducts();
    // this.id=this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.id = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get['id'];
    this.productService.getById(this.id)
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe(x => this.productValidation.patchValue(x));
  
    this.productValidation = this.formBuilder.group({
      productCode: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5), Validators.maxLength(50)]],
      productName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5), Validators.maxLength(50), Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z ]*$')]],
      bottleType: ['', [Validators.required]],
      palletType: ['', [Validators.required]],
      palletNumber: ['', [Validators.required]],
      recipeCode: ['', [Validators.required]],
      startBrix: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.min(0), Validators.max(11)]],
      endBrix: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.min(0), Validators.max(11)]],
      startCo2: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.min(0), Validators.max(10)]],
      endCo2: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.min(0), Validators.max(10)]],
      maschineCode: ['', [Validators.required]],
      expiryStartDate: [new FormControl((new Date())), [Validators.required]],
      expiryEndDate: [new FormControl((new Date())), [Validators.required]],
      nitrogen: [false],
      weight: ['', [Validators.required]],
      waterId: [''],
    });

    this.loadProducts();
    this.id=this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.productService.getById(this.id)
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe(x => this.productValidation.patchValue(x));


  }





 private loadProducts() {
    this.productService.getById(this.id).pipe(first()).subscribe((data: ProductResponse) => {
      this.products = data.products;
    });

  }

Product Service
  getById(id:string): Observable<ProductResponse> {

    return this.httpclient.get<ProductResponse>('https://localhost:xxxx/api/Products/'+id).pipe(
      map((data) => data),
      catchError((error) => throwError(error))
    );
  }

}

export interface ProductResponse {
  products: Update_Products[ 

  ];
}

Html:
<div class="container-fluid">
    <p style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold; font-size: 20px;color: rgb(13, 13, 190);">Update Product</p>
    <form  [formGroup]="productValidation" >
  
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="product-update">
            <mat-label>Product Code</mat-label>
            <input matInput #txtproductcode formControlName="productCode" >
            <mat-error *ngIf="productValidation.get('productCode')?.hasError('required')">
              Product Code is Required!
            </mat-error>
            <mat-error *ngIf="productValidation.get('productCode')?.hasError('minlength')">
              Product Code should be atleast 5 characters long!
            </mat-error>
            <mat-error *ngIf="productValidation.get('productCode')?.hasError('maxlength')">
              Product Code can be atmax 50 characters long!
            </mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>


          <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="product-update">
            <mat-label>Product Name</mat-label>
            <input matInput #txtproductname formControlName="productName">
            <mat-error *ngIf="productValidation.get('productName')?.hasError('required')">
              Product Name is Required!
            </mat-error>
            <mat-error *ngIf="productValidation.get('productName')?.hasError('minlength')">
              Product Name should be atleast 5 characters long!
            </mat-error>
            <mat-error *ngIf="productValidation.get('productName')?.hasError('maxlength')">
              Product Name can be atmax 50 characters long!
            </mat-error>
            <mat-error *ngIf="productValidation.get('productName')?.hasError('pattern')">
              Product Name not matched by pattern!
            </mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>

          <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="product-update">
            <mat-label>Bottle Type</mat-label>
            <input matInput #bottletype formControlName="bottleType">
            <mat-error *ngIf="productValidation.get('bottleType')?.hasError('required')">
              Bottle type is Required!
            </mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
  
          <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="product-update">
            <mat-label>Pallet Type</mat-label>
            <input matInput #pallettype formControlName="palletType">
            <mat-error *ngIf="productValidation.get('palletType')?.hasError('required')">
              Pallet type is Required!
            </mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
  
          <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="product-update">
            <mat-label>Pallet Number</mat-label>
            <input matInput #palletnumber formControlName="palletNumber">
            <mat-error *ngIf="productValidation.get('palletNumber')?.hasError('required')">
              Pallet number is Required!
            </mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>


          <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="product-update">
            <mat-label>Recipe Code</mat-label>
            <input matInput #recipecode formControlName="recipeCode">
            <mat-error *ngIf="productValidation.get('recipeCode')?.hasError('required')">
              Recipe code is Required!
            </mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
  
          <section class="product-update">
            <mat-checkbox #nitrogen formControlName="nitrogen" class="example-margin">Nitrogen
            </mat-checkbox>
          </section>
  
          <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="product-update">
            <mat-label>Start Brix</mat-label>
            <input matInput type="number" min="0" value="0" #startbrix formControlName="startBrix">
            <mat-error *ngIf="productValidation.get('startBrix')?.hasError('required')">
              Start Brix value is Required!
            </mat-error>
            <mat-error *ngIf="productValidation.get('startBrix')?.hasError('min')">
              Start Brix value cannot be negative!
            </mat-error>
            <mat-error *ngIf="productValidation.get('startBrix')?.hasError('max')">
              Start Brix value cannot be more than 10!
            </mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
  
  
          <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="product-update">
            <mat-label>End Brix</mat-label>
            <input matInput type="number" min="0" value="0" #endbrix formControlName="endBrix">
            <mat-error *ngIf="productValidation.get('endBrix')?.hasError('required')">
              End Brix value is Required!
            </mat-error>
            <mat-error *ngIf="productValidation.get('endBrix')?.hasError('min')">
              End Brix value cannot be negative!
            </mat-error>
            <mat-error *ngIf="productValidation.get('endBrix')?.hasError('max')">
              End Brix value cannot be more than 10!
            </mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
  
          <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="product-update" >
            <mat-label>Start CO2</mat-label>
            <input matInput type="number" min="0" value="0" #startco2 formControlName="startCo2">
            <mat-error *ngIf="productValidation.get('startCo2')?.hasError('required')">
              Start CO2 value is Required!
            </mat-error>
            <mat-error *ngIf="productValidation.get('startCo2')?.hasError('min')">
              Start CO2 value cannot be negative!
            </mat-error>
            <mat-error *ngIf="productValidation.get('startCo2')?.hasError('max')">
              Start CO2 value cannot be more than 10!
            </mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
  
  
          <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="product-update" >
            <mat-label>End CO2</mat-label>
            <input matInput type="number" min="0" value="0" #endco2 formControlName="endCo2" >
            <mat-error *ngIf="productValidation.get('endCo2')?.hasError('required')">
              End CO2 value is Required!
            </mat-error>
            <mat-error *ngIf="productValidation.get('endCo2')?.hasError('min')">
              End CO2 value cannot be negative!
            </mat-error>
            <mat-error *ngIf="productValidation.get('endCo2')?.hasError('max')">
              End CO2 value cannot be more than 10!
            </mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>

          <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="product-update">
            <mat-label>Weight</mat-label>
            <input matInput type="number" min="0" value="0" #weight formControlName="weight">
            <mat-error *ngIf="productValidation.get('weight')?.hasError('required')">
              Weight value is Required!
            </mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
  
  
  
          <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="product-update">
            <mat-label>Maschine Code</mat-label>
            <input matInput #maschinecode formControlName="maschineCode">
            <mat-error *ngIf="productValidation.get('maschineCode')?.hasError('required')">
              Maschine code is Required!
            </mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>

          <div>
            <mat-form-field class="product-update">
              <mat-label>Water</mat-label>
              <mat-select formControlName="waterId">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let water of waters" [value]="water.id">
                  {{water?.waterType}}
                </mat-option>
              </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>
          </div>
  
  
  
          <mat-form-field class="product-update">
            <mat-label>Enter a date range</mat-label>
            <mat-date-range-input [rangePicker]="picker" >
              <input matStartDate placeholder="Start date" #expiryStartDate formControlName="expiryStartDate"
                data-date-format='YYYY-MM-DD'>
              <mat-error *ngIf="productValidation.get('expiryStartDate')?.hasError('required')">
                Expire date end value is Required!
              </mat-error>
              <input matEndDate placeholder="End date" #expiryenddate formControlName="expiryEndDate"
                data-date-format='YYYY-MM-DD'>
              <mat-error *ngIf="productValidation.get('expiryEndDate')?.hasError('required')">
                Expire date end value is Required!
              </mat-error>
            </mat-date-range-input>
            <mat-hint>YYYY/MM/DD – YYYY/MM/DD</mat-hint>
  
            <mat-datepicker-toggle matIconSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
            <mat-date-range-picker #picker></mat-date-range-picker>
          </mat-form-field>
  
      <div style="text-align: center; width: auto;">
     <div style="margin:5px; display: inline-block;"><button mat-raised-button class="btn" color="primary" (click)="update()"
            >Create</button>
        </div>
  </div>
</form>

Update_Products
export class Update_Products {
  
  productCode : string;
  productName : string;
  bottleType : string;
  palletType : string;
  palletNumber : string;
  recipeCode : string;
  startBrix : number;
  endBrix : number;
  startCo2 : number;
  endCo2 : number;
  maschineCode : string;
  expiryStartDate : Date | string;
  expiryEndDate : Date | string;
  nitrogen :Boolean;
  weight :number;
  watertype :string;
}

dialog:
  update(id: string) {
    this.dialogService.openDialog({
      componentType: UpdateComponent,
      data: id,
      options: {
        width: "800px",
        height:"700px"
      }
    });
  }



please share the parent and child component structure HTML and the URL of the current component

I edited the form.Thank you very much for your help.

You definitely need to share the component (parent) on which you perform the click, and from which you get (don't get) the undefined route id

@Mustafasan could you share routing and the browser url that has the issue

I understand the problem now. Since I did not define any route in the app routing section, the route operation cannot be performed and I receive an undefined response. Thank you very much for your help. It took me about 5 hours but it was solved. :D
